# Creating unique IDs for XElement at runtime LinqToXml

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq-to-xml

How do you create unique Id's for an XElement at runtime. Im using an object datasource for inerting XElements and I need to generate id's for the newly inserted XElement so I can return it id value

Comment: Would you like to explain a bit more about your scenario?

Comment: Pretty much the same way you would generate any unique id.  Use a generator or order them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you looking for `Guid.NewGuid()`

**Edit**

KDM provided a useful link http://www.joe-stevens.com/2010/01/08/linq-to-xml-tutorial/

Comment: Yeah you can do that but i just found a link that shows what todo http://www.joe-stevens.com/2010/01/08/linq-to-xml-tutorial/

Comment: I'll mark this as answered even tho it wasn't quite what i was looking for

Comment: @KDM nice link, thanks for sharing but it is using Integer as unique id and then there is bit of logic to workout uniqueness of ID , In IMO Guid.NewGuid() is a simpler way of getting unique IDs.But if that solves your purpose then you good to go with it :).

Comment: what do you mean uniqueness it generates the next id after descending then adds 1 number extra whats un-unique doing that way

Comment: It is fine, if that solves your problem , you should go with it, I generally prefers to use something from framework it self :)

Comment: Well it does work and the framework is just as good as you suggested I hope others find this question usefull

Comment: I included your link for the completion.